# Nginx as apache reverse proxy giving 404's on .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use Nginx as reverse proxy with Apache to cache static files, etc.
I'm having an issue on a new install, that it's not passing on URIs to Apache.
Basically I have a vBulletin forum, and I'm using vBSEO as the SEO proxy. 
The problem is it's generating 404s for every URL, except files that already exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you possibly give us the relevant portion of your nginx configuration? A.t.m. we cannot guess what's wrong (although one might:  using 'localhost' when not in the hosts file, so not resolving to 127.0.0.1, wrong portnumber for apache, forgetting to add a host header, etc.). Normally, It'd be something like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;

    # normally some checking here for static content which exists as file 
    # like images, js, etc, with a 'break', with at the end:

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:<portnumber apache is on>/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I traced it down to the SEO friendly plugin ( vBSEO ). It was producing links with .html extension and it seems nginx had it set for caching. Since those links didn't exist physically, it was producing the 404s.

Comment: Ah, you do know you can let nginx check for the existance of a file and resort to proxying if not found?

Comment: Well that was already added to the rules. The basic fact was that it was proxying all together because the extension was there.